# how to upload images into folder which in parent directory

Tags: php

I have following directory structure.

```
 [root_folder]
   [admin]
       [assets]
          [images]
       [classes]
          upload.php
     index.php
   [assets]
       [images]
index.php
```

I want to upload images into **root_folder > assets > images**.

I tried below codes on index.php which is in admin folder.

**root_directory > admin > index.php**

```
<?php
require_once "classes/upload.php";

$upload_handler = new Upload_images();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $folder_toUpload = 'assets/images/';
    $fileName = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    $fileTemp = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $upload_handler->upload($folder_toUpload, $fileName, $fileTemp);
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     Select File:
     <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" />
     <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit" />
</form>
```

**root_directory > classes > upload.php**.

```
<?php
class Upload_images
{
    public function upload($folder_toUpload, $fileName, $fileTemp)
    {
        $target_path = $folder_toUpload . $fileName;
        if (move_uploaded_file($fileTemp, $target_path)) {
            echo $target_path;
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, file not uploaded, please try again!";
        }
    }
}
```

these codes work fine but it uploads images into **root_direcory > admin > assets > images**.

I want to upload images into **root_directory > assets > images**.

how do i upload?

Answer (score 0):

**In PHP**

```
<?php
require_once "classes/upload.php";

$upload_handler = new Upload_images();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $folder_toUpload = '../assets/images/'; //or use this $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/images/';
    $fileName = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
    $fileTemp = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $upload_handler->upload($folder_toUpload, $fileName, $fileTemp);
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you explain how to get basr_url for  **root_directory > assets > images** ?

Comment: @najubudeendeveloper which framework are you use?? base_url() function is for codeigniter.

Comment: @najubudeendeveloper In Codeigniter `base_url()` define in config.php file

Comment: i don't  use any framework. i try to do it using core php.

Comment: @najubudeendeveloper So use first part of answer with `$folder_toUpload = '/assets/images/';` See Edited Answer

Comment: i tried as you said but it shows an error like **Warning: move_uploaded_file(/assets/images/bg-new.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\php\test_moveUploaded\admin\classes\upload.php on line 7**.

Comment: @najubudeendeveloper try this `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/assets/images/'`

Comment: again i get errors like **Warning: move_uploaded_file(C:/wamp64/www/assets/images/bg-new.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\php\test_moveUploaded\admin\classes\upload.php on line 7** and **Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp64\tmp\php1BE5.tmp' to 'C:/wamp64/www/assets/images/bg-new.jpg' in C:\wamp64\www\php\test_moveUploaded\admin\classes\upload.php on line 7**.

Comment: @najubudeendeveloper Try this `$folder_toUpload = '../assets/images/';` and check this https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths

Comment: Please Accept and Upvote Answer to help other @najubudeendeveloper